# Passing array of strings from JS to C# inside WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, com, interop

I'm using ObjectForScripting property to interact with web page inside WebBrowser control and everything works fine except I can't figure out how to pass array of strings back to C#

HTML code

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.external.save(Array('test', 'test2'))" />
```

Form

```
// Returns System.__ComObject
public void Save(object parameters)
{
}

// Throws an exception
public void Save(object[] parameters)
{
}

// Also throws an exception
public void Save(string[] parameters)
{
}
```

Comment: Did you find a working approach?

Comment: No. I read many negative responses about passing back arrays back to calling application. In the end I ended up with re-factored program where I have multiple method arguments instead of array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than fight it; maybe approach the problem from another angle... could you (instead, either of):

- delimit the data (with `Array.join`) and pass a *single* string, and split it (`string.Split`) in the C#
- call Save multiple times, accepting a single string each time (`Save(string s)`), then call a final method to actually commit the changes

Comment: I could. I suspect you are suggesting that because marshaling objects from JS to .NET is tricky and doesn't worth it if workaround is possible. Are you?

Comment: @Sergej pretty much, yes. It doesn't want to work the way you are showing... so don't do that ;p

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous object instead of an array on the javascript side:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.external.save({first: 'test', second: 'test2'})" />
```

On the C# side (you need to use .NET 4.0 or more for the dynamic or use Type.InvokeMember if you are on an older version):

```
public void Save(dynamic parameters)
{
  MessageBox.Show(parameters.first);
  MessageBox.Show(parameters.second); 
}
```

Not tested, but I think you can use reflection to discover the members.

Also look at this: http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.fr/2009/11/vbnetcnet-communication-with-javascript.html

Comment: It worked and i prefered it instead of serializing and unserializing data.

Answer (score 0):

```
function JS2VBArray( objJSArray )
{
    var dictionary = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.Dictionary" );
    for ( var i = 0; i < objJSArray.length; i++ )
    {
        dictionary.add( i, objJSArray[ i ] );
    }

    return dictionary.Items();
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(v=vs.80).aspx

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.external.Save( JS2VBArray( ['test', 'test2'] ) )" />
```

This should go to the method.

```
public void Save(object[] parameters)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string array is automatically passed as a comma-delimited string.
So this call:

```
window.external.save(Array('test', 'test2'));
```

Is received like so:

```
public void save(string fromjs)
{
    string[] result = fromjs.Split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late for this, but typically when I need to pass objects or, in this case Arrays, I pass them as a JSON string.

```
var sArr = JSON.stringify(myArr);
window.external(sArr);
```

Then I have a `JavaScriptSerializer` on the other side that deserializes it back into an object / array.

[Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

To pass an array I found this to not be supported directly. I took the approach recommended by Marc Gravell to call multiple times but structured it in 3 methods instead, that are used in sequence: `InitArgs`, `PushArg` (multiple times), `FinalArgs`.

```
private System.Collections.Generics.Queue<string> _argsQ;
public void InitArgs()
{
    _argsQ = new System.Collections.Generics.Queue<string>();
}
public void PushArg(string arg)
{
    _argsQ.Enqueue(arg);
}
public void FinalArgs()
{
    string[] parameters = _argsQ.ToArray();
    // Save parameters
}
```

Now method calls can be used sequentially from html/js:

```
...onclick="var params = ['test', 'test2']; window.external.InitArgs(); for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++) window.external.PushArg(params[i]); window.external.FinalArgs();"...
```